# How do I import a JavaScript module in a Django project?

Tags: javascript, django, google-analytics

I have no clue what so ever how to import this JavaScript module with the Google Analytics Embed API:

```
import AccountSummaries from 'javascript-api-utils/lib/account-summaries';
```

I get these errors in my browser:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
Uncaught TypeError: gapi.analytics.ext.ViewSelector2 is not a constructor
```

This is my project structure:

```
project_name
    app_name
        static
          js
            app_name
               ga-dev-tools
                    embed-api
                        components
                            view-selector2.js
               javascript-api-utils
                   lib
                     account-summaries
                         account-summaries.js
```

Why do I get these errors? How can I import it properly with Django?

Comment: The Google Analytics embed API is written in Javascript. Django is written in Python. You can't mix them in that way.

Comment: @solarissmoke Yes, I know. But how do I import the AccountSummaries to my other js file?

Comment: {% static 'js/app_name/javascript-api-utils/lib/account-summaries/account-summaries.js' %}

into your template file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you entered type="module" in script tag.

```
<script type="module" src="{% static 'yourJsFile.js' %}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

you cannot do what you're trying to do, and I think you don't completely understand how a full stack application's parts interact with each other. I suggest that you should do some research before you try to dive into the deep end with this API.

you could make a javascript file which utilizes the API and then serves the information yielded via your google API through post requests via ajax or some other method to your django backend